# запрос, который конвертирует сумму транзакции в евро

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE Bank_operation (
Customer_id INT ,
Date_id date Primary key,
Transaction_amount INT);

CREATE TABLE Rates (
Date_id date Primary key,
Ccy_code INT,
Rate decimal (5,2),
FOREIGN KEY (Date_id)  REFERENCES bank_operation (Date_id));

INSERT INTO Bank_operation VALUES (123658, '2022-03-12', 6500 );
INSERT INTO Rates VALUES ( '2022-02.21', 230, 70.65 );
INSERT INTO Rates VALUES ( '2022.05.15', 230, 72.20 );
```

Я хочу написать запрос, который будет конвертировать сумму транзакции в eur (ccy_code = 230), учитывая, что в таблице Rates есть данные только по будним дням, а транзакции, которые были сделаны в выходные, должны быть пересчитаны по курсу последнего рабочего дня.

Результат, который я хочу получить

`Customer_id` `Date_id` `Total`

Вот мой пример запроса, но я не понимаю почему он работает. Может мне необходимо отредактировать сами таблицы или проблема в самом запросе, я уже не знаю, что мне пробовать

```
SELECT Customer_id, Rates.Date_id,  
      Transaction_amount / ( SELECT Rate
                       FROM Rates
                       WHERE Rates.Date_id = Bank_operation.Date_id
                       ORDER BY Rates.Date_id DESC
                       LIMIT 1 ) AS total
FROM Bank_operation;
```

Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: Исправьте синтаксические ошибки в примере данных, Покажите требуемый результат - с подробными пояснениями.

Comment: Здравствуйте, я не очень понимаю о каких синтаксических ошибках вы говорите, т.е вы имеете ввиду ошибки при создании таблиц или ошибки в коде с решением?  Также я описал проблему и результат, который хочу получить, поэтому не очень понимаю что мне нужно еще добавить в описание

Comment: *я не очень понимаю о каких синтаксических ошибках вы говорите* Очень плохо, что Вы даже не удосужились проверить работоспособность выложенного кода. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a90a605d94fd6317c85f072721a06d4 *Также я описал проблему и **результат**, который хочу получить* Ну и где он, этот результат? Где тот набор записей, который должен вернуть запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала стоит отказаться от PRIMARY KEY и FOREIGN KEY на полях типа DATE, так как на одну и туже дату у Вас может быть несколько различных записей о платежах в таблице Bank_operation, а такая организация БД этого не позволит. Тоже касается и таблицы с курсами валют Rates, такая организация не позволит внести курсы других валют на одну и ту же дату. Более того, если оставить всё как есть, то вылетит ошибка при попытке выполнить вставки в таблицу Rates, так вторичные ключи обоих записей ('2022.02.21' и '2022.05.15') будет ссылаться на несуществующую запись в таблице Bank_operation (там только '2022.03.12'). Таким образом я бы написал так:

```
   CREATE TABLE Bank_operation (
   Customer_id INT ,
   Date_id DATE,
   Transaction_amount INT
   );

   CREATE TABLE Rates (
   Date_id DATE,
   Ccy_code INT,
   Rate decimal (5,2)
   );

   INSERT INTO Bank_operation VALUES (123658, '2022.03.12', 6500 );
   INSERT INTO Rates VALUES ( '2022.02.21', 230, 70.65 );
   INSERT INTO Rates VALUES ( '2022.05.15', 230, 72.20 );
```

Теперь рассмотрим запрос. У Вас будет ошибка в строке SELECT Customer_id, **Rates**.Date_id, ...  таблицу Rates Вы используете только в подзапросе и на неё ссылаться в выводе результата нельзя. Ну и собственно условие, если последний известный курс записан датой ранее, то нужно поставить условие < (меньше), тогда всё заработает.

```
SELECT 
    b.Customer_id, 
    b.Date_id,  
    b.Transaction_amount / 
    ( SELECT r.Rate FROM Rates r
    WHERE r.Date_id < b.Date_id AND r.Ccy_code = 230
    ORDER BY r.Date_id DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS total
FROM Bank_operation b;
```

Надеюсь, я смог Вам помочь.